# approximate pi by iteration JAVA

Tags: java, pi

I am trying to approximate pi by iteration. This is only a portion of the code.

I'm trying to put this equation into java: pi = 4(1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 + ... + ((-1)^(i+1)) / (2i - 1) ). The problem I have is the summation of this equation (illustrated in my code). If the user keeps on entering y, the program is supposed to multiply i by 2 and calculate pi until user enters n, then it returns to the main menu.

```
    else if(input == 4)
    {
        System.out.print("i=1 pi=4.0\tWould you like to continue? (y|n) ");     
        char y = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        if (y =='y')
        {
            for (int i=2; i<=1000; i=i*2)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                double pi =4 * (Math.pow(-1, i+1)/(2*i-1));
                //Right here, how do I modify it to get a sum across a multitude of i's?
                System.out.print("i=" + i + " " + "pi" + "=" + pi + "\tcontinue (y|n)? " );
                keyboard.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }   
        else
        {

        }
```

Comment: Why do you multiply `i` by 2? shouldn't that be `i++` instead?

Comment: `Math.pow(-1, i+1)` this won't work either.

Comment: The increment of i is supposed to be two times the previous i

Comment: If you look at the difference between `1/3`, `1/5`, `1/7`, etc. you're just increasing the denominator by 2 each time.  Use that in your loop.

Comment: **This question might have been answered already:** [link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70053809/9345726)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the difference between the summation equation using `i` and the programmatic way to loop through a calculation.  Something like this will loop through `i`s adding/subtracting the fraction, and then multiply it all by 4 in the end.

```
boolean plus = true
double sum = 0;
for (double i=1.0; i<=1000; i+=2.0)
{
    if (plus) {
        sum += 1.0/i;
        plus = false;
    } else {
        sum -= 1.0/i;
        plus = true;
    }
}
sum *= 4;
```

Comment: Won't `1/i` be integer division and therefore always `0` when `i > 1`?