# Java Pi calculator getting stuck

Tags: java, pi

I recently made a Pi calculator in Java and when I run it, it defines Pi down to the same amount incredibly fast but then it gets stuck at 3.141592653589787 and only outputs that. Here's my code if anyone can help figure out what's happening.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = 2;
    double b = 3;
    double c = 4;
    double z = 3;

    while (true) {
        double x = a*b*c;
        double y = 4/x;
        z+=y;
        a+=2;
        b+=2;
        c+=2;

        x = a*b*c;
        y = 4/x;
        z-=y;
        a+=2;
        b+=2;
        c+=2;
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do understand that there are only finitely many values that can be stored in a `double`, right?  You might be better off using a `BigDecimal` if you're looking for arbitrary precision.

Comment: you can eliminate 4 and simply the `x` expression to `n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)` and get rid of `a,b,c`.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use this code for the PI approach from the rectangles approximates:

```
    int rectangleCount = 100;
    double width = 0.0;
    double pi = 0.0;
    double height = 0.0;
    double radius = 1.0;
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= rectangleCount; i++) {
        
        width = (double)i / rectangleCount;
        
        height = Math.sqrt(radius - width*width);
        
        pi = pi + (radius/rectangleCount) *height;
    }
    pi = pi + 1.0/rectangleCount; //first rectangle

    System.out.println(pi*4);
```

Basically the count of the rectangles you choose, doesn't matter. The first rectangle always has the same radius and width, while the rest of the rectangles can be calculated in the for loop.